# UIAlertController View not appearing on Map when using calloutAccessoryControlTapped method in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, mkannotation

I am creating my first IOS app and am having a very difficult time understanding why the CalloutAccessoryControlTapped Control function is not working.

The Info button is appearing on the annotation, but when the user taps on the Info button, nothing happens.  See screenshot here: [Screenshot of Annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djLB8.png).

I created a function in the View Controller to add the Callout accessory view and suspect there is something wrong with the function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Here is the Function:**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
               let annotation = view.annotation as? Fire
               let status = "Fire Status: Active"
               let distance = "Fire Location: 25 miles away"
               let ac = UIAlertController(title: status, message: distance, preferredStyle: .alert)
               ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default))
            self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
               }
```

**Here is the code from my View Controller -- updated 4/20/2021:**

```
import MapKit
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class FireMapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var FireMapView: MKMapView!
    
    let mapView = MKMapView()
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    var lat = Double()
    var lon = Double()
    var fires: [Fire] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupMapView()
        checkLocationServices()
        mapView.register(FireMarkerView.self,forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:
            MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
        
       
    //Initiate URL Session to get Fire data and add Fire data to the Map Annotations
        if let url = URL(string: "https://services3.arcgis.com/T4QMspbfLg3qTGWY/arcgis/rest/services/Active_Fires/FeatureServer/0/query?outFields=*&where=1%3D1&f=geojson") {
              
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, response, error in
                    if let data = data {
                       do {
                           let features = try MKGeoJSONDecoder().decode(data)
                               .compactMap { $0 as? MKGeoJSONFeature }
                             let validWorks = features.compactMap(Fire.init)
                        self.fires.append(contentsOf: validWorks)
                              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.mapView.addAnnotations(self.fires)
                              }
                                 }
                       catch let error {
                                    print(error)
                       }
                    
                        

                    }
                 }.resume()
        }
   
    }
    
    
    func setupMapView() {
        view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        mapView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        mapView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
   
    func checkLocationServices() {
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            setupLocationManager()
            locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(locationManager)
        } else {
            // the user didn't turn it on
        }
    }

//Get the current location permissions for User

func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {

    switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedAlways , .authorizedWhenInUse:
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true
            followUserLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break
        case .notDetermined , .denied , .restricted:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
        default:
            break
    }
    
    switch manager.accuracyAuthorization {
        case .fullAccuracy:
            break
        case .reducedAccuracy:
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
    
    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location.coordinate, latitudinalMeters:  160934, longitudinalMeters:  160934)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        print("Fire Map User Location on Map:", location.coordinate)
        
// Call stopUpdatingLocation() to stop listening for location updates,
// other wise this function will be called every time when user location changes.
// Need a solution for this.
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func followUserLocation() {
        if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: 4000, longitudinalMeters: 4000)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(locationManager)
    }
    


//Function to display additional Fire data after User selects the Callout Info button on the Annotation

      func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
              let annotation = view.annotation as? Fire
            print("callout Accessory Tapped!")
            let status = "Fire Status: Active"
              let distance = "Fire Location: 25 miles away"
              let ac = UIAlertController(title: status, message: distance, preferredStyle: .alert)
              ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default))
           self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
              }
}
```

**Here is the Class for the Annotation:**

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class FireMarkerView: MKAnnotationView {
  override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
      guard let fire = newValue as? Fire else {
        return
      }
      canShowCallout = true
      calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
      rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
      image = fire.image
    }
  }
}
```

**Here is the Class for the Model:**

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class Fire: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
  let title: String?
  let county: String?
  let city: String?
  let incidentTypeCategory: String?
  let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  let percentContained: Int?
  let lastUpdateDateTime: Int?
    

  init(
    title: String?,
    county: String?,
    city: String?,
    incidentTypeCategory: String?,
    coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,
    percentContained: Int?,
    lastUpdateDateTime: Int?
  ) {
    self.title = title
    self.county = county
    self.city = city
    self.incidentTypeCategory = incidentTypeCategory
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.percentContained = percentContained
    self.lastUpdateDateTime = lastUpdateDateTime

    super.init()
  }


init?(feature: MKGeoJSONFeature) {
  // 1
  guard
    let point = feature.geometry.first as? MKPointAnnotation,
    let propertiesData = feature.properties,
    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: propertiesData),
    let properties = json as? [String: Any]
    else {
      return nil
  }

  // 2
    
  title = ((properties["IncidentName"] as? String ?? "Unknown") + " Wildfire")
  county = ((properties["POOCounty"] as? String ?? "Unknown") + " County")
  city = properties["POOCity"] as? String
  incidentTypeCategory = properties["IncidentTypeCategory"] as? String
  coordinate = point.coordinate
  percentContained = properties["PercentContained"] as? Int
  lastUpdateDateTime =  properties["ModifiedOnDateTime_dt"] as? Int
  
  super.init()
}
    var subtitle: String? {
        return (county)
    }
    
    var image: UIImage {
      guard let name = incidentTypeCategory else {
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "RedFlame")
      }

      switch name {
      case "RX":
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "YellowFlame")
      default:
        return #imageLiteral(resourceName: "RedFlame")
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the method even called? If yes, is there any error message in console? Like presenting already in view hierarchy, or no present, etc. ?

Comment: @Larme, please forgive the prior message, I debugged the function and there were no error messages in the console.  Any idea why the function wasn't called?

Comment: Your code is a mess.  Your viewDidLoad has a never-ending story.

Comment: @ElTomato, Hi thanks for looking at this.  This is my very first app and I have had no training so am trying my best.  I updated the View Controller code.  Could you please take a look?  Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I suggest you fix your code before seeking an additiional round of assistance.